# LVM or alternative that have the features of Windows Storage Spaces?

Tags: linux, lvm, storage-spaces

I currently run a small home media server on a Windows machine. I'd like to swap it to a small compute stick of some sort running a thin linux distro.

However, the reason I chose Windows to begin with was because of the Storage Spaces feature. Many will say "it's just LVM" but from what I've read on the features of LVM, it's lacking at least this feature I want:

- Slices of data and that store a parity slice on some drive other than the 2 drives they're stored on for data access.

This effectively allows me to mix-and-match drives of different sizes/types any-which-way I want and still have at least a parity backup of my data. This being just a media server, I don't really care about whether raid 10 levels of resilience or how fast the storage really is (so long as I can stream a 4k compressed video off it reliably via the single USB 3 connection to the Drobo, I'm good).

What I care about is that if I add another drive to my pool, I don't have to add 3 identical drives.

Is there any such feature in Linux? From what I've read, LVM can't really do this.

Comment: `single USB 3 connection to the Drobo` ... what?  I would be tempted to suggest ZFS, if you can at least do pairs of drives.  Drive removal is not an option though, at least not in the short term.

Comment: I'd stay away from Drobo. There are too many issues with their BeyondRAID, and it's proprietary layout: You can't read disks w/out Drobo appliance.

Comment: I don't use a Drobo NAS. It's just an external enclosure that holds multiple 3.5" drives. Think of it as having multiple 3.5" drives.

Answer (score 5):

LVM supports thin provisioning just fine!

http://www.linuxtechi.com/thin-provisioned-logical-volumes-centos-7-rhel-7/

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmthin.7.html

Comment: I clarified my question. It isn't thin provisioning per say that I was asking for. It was the ability to effectively do RAID5 on thin data slices using different drives. So a 1GB file can be stored as:

1. 256MB slices split across drive0-drive1 and 256MB parity stored on drive2.
2. Other pieces of 256MB slices split across drive0-drive2 and a parity backup on drive3.

This allows me to mix-and-match different sized drives yet still benefit from RAID5.